# treemap vs arraylist - perfomance & resources while iterating/adding/editing values

Tags: java, performance, arraylist, resources, treemap

Talking about performance and resources.

Which one is faster and needs less resources when adding and editing values, ArrayList or TreeMap?

Or is there any type of data that can beat these two? (it has to be able to somehow make the data sorted)

Comment: What exactly is the performance or resource usage issue you are running into? If you are "just wondering", don't do premature optimization: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premature_optimization#When_to_optimize

Comment: Thanks for your input, right now I'm working with around 50 000 records retrived from a database. But they may go up to 500 000.

Comment: Unless each item is really big, your computer will still be able to handle these amounts lightning-fast. Remember that this is in-memory-operations we are talking about here.

Comment: My point is: Don't assume that you will run into a problem. Do a test. Create an ArrayList with 500 000 entries, and handle it. If you run into trouble, think about alternatives. Thinking about performance and resource usage too soon will just ruin your program. This is years and years of painful experience talking, here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depends on what you need.

If we are talking about **sorted data**, as the `ArrayList` is a list/array, if it is sorted, you could get a value in `O(log n)` speed. To insert, though, it is `O(n)`, because you potentially have to move the whole array when inserting a new element.

The `TreeMap` data structure is implemented as a **red-black tree**, which both the insertion time and search time are `O(log n)`.

So, in a nutshell:

```
Data Structure         Insertion Speed    Search Speed
ArrayList (sorted)     O(n)               O(log n)
TreeMap                O(log n)           O(log n)
```

I'd definitely go with a `TreeMap`. It has the additional bonus of having it all ready to go right now (you'd have to implement some of the code yourself to make the `ArrayList` work).

**Note:**

If you don't get the `O(n)` (called big-Oh) notation, think of it as a formula for the amount seconds needed when the structure has `n` elements. So, if you had an `ArrayList` with 1000 elements (`n=1000`), it'd take `3` seconds (`log 1000 = 3`) to find an item there. It would take 1000 seconds to insert a new element though.

The `TreeMap`, on the other hand, would take **3** seconds to both search **and** insert.

Answer (score 6):

ArrayLists and TreeMaps are different types of structures meant for different things.  It would be helpful to know what you are planning on using these structures for.

**ArrayList**

- Allows duplicates (it is a List)
- Amortized O(1) to add to the end of the list
- O(n) to insert anywhere else in the list
- O(1) to access
- O(n) to remove

**TreeMap**

- Does not allow duplicate keys (it is a Map)
- O(logn) to insert
- O(logn) to access
- O(logn) to remove

Sorting the ArrayList will take O(nlogn) time (after inserting everything), while the TreeMap will always be sorted.

**EDIT**

You've mentioned that you are working with records retrieved from a database.  Since they are coming from a DB, I would assume that they are already sorted - in which case you should just insert them one by one into an ArrayList.

Answer (score 4):

ArrayList requires only O(1) to add and editing a value since you're only accessing it with the index. However, searching an element in a ArrayList is O(n) because you have to get through at most all the elements of the list.

But you have to be aware of what data structures you will implement. It's hard to choose betwen an ArrayList and a TreeMap since they are not really for the same purpose(a Map doesn't allow duplicates but not an ArrayList, etc.).

Here's two sheet which describes the differences between both (and others type of collections too).

`List` and `Map` :
[image]

Added `Set` too :

[image]